# TSP with knapsack combo

Tags: knapsack-problems, traveling-salesman

My problem statement is that my agent has to visit multiple pickup points once to collect orders, say Item A, Item B, Item C...... etc. We are using TSP for that. 
Now say Item A are stored in 3 places and each place has stocks which are 20,30 and 40 respectively. If my total quantity of pickup for Item A is 45 then how do I choose the optimal path? 
Do we have any particular algorithm for this? I have heard of the Travelling Producer problem but did not find much details on it.

Comment: you can model your problem by constraint programming with google ortools.
https://developers.google.com/optimization?hl=vi